# Checking string content returns unexpected results

Tags: java

I have to write a method called `ghostHunters()` that accepts a *String* as a parameter. The method should determinte if the *String* contains the word *boo*. If the *String* contains *boo* but has more than two *o*, the method should return `false`.

So far, I have managed to develop a code which works ok in some cases. However, it does not work if I type in a *String* like `Bob says boo`.

Any suggestions?

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String word)
{
    word = word.toLowerCase()+ " ";
    if(word.contains("boo") && word.length() > 3)
    {
        word = word.substring(word.indexOf("b"),word.indexOf("b")+4);
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length()- 2; i++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'b' && word.charAt(i+1) == 'o'&& word.charAt(i+2) == 'o' && word.charAt(i+3) != 'o')
            {
                return true;  
            }
        }
        word = word.substring(word.indexOf("b"),word.indexOf("b")+4);
    }
    else if(word.contains("boo"))
        return true;
    return false;

}
```

Comment: if 'boob' is passed should true be returned? And what about 'boob said boo'?

Comment: Maybe the time has come to accept an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If "boo" is located at the end of the word, `word.substring(word.indexOf("b"),word.indexOf("b")+4)` will give you `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `word.indexOf("b")+2` is the last index of the String, and `substring` tries to return the characters whose indices are from `word.indexOf("b")` to `word.indexOf("b")+3`.

You must check that `word.indexOf("b")+4 <= word.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you type **Bob says boo**, then it returns false because **Bob** also has an **o**, which is counted along with the two o's in the word **boo**. Hence, the total number of o's become 3, which is greater than 2. Thus is returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Could be more efficient, but it works, so you can work out why your method is lacking.

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String s)
{
    String str = s.toLowerCase();
    int oCount = 0;

    if(s.contains("boo"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'o' && ++oCount == 3) return false;
        }           
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String word) {
    if (word == null)
        return false;
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if (word.length() < 3)
        return false;
    if (!word.contains("boo"))
        return false;
    else if (word.length() == 3) 
        return true;

    int index = word.indexOf("boo");
    if (word.charAt(index+1) != 'o')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try this solution:

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String word) {

    word = word.toLowerCase() + "";
    if (word.contains("boo") && word.length() > 3) {
        if (word.contains("booo"))
        return false;
        else
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

It checks if the string contains more than two `o` after a `b`, and that's exactly what you need.

Comment: What if the word contains more than 3 o distributed in the string? It should return false, but your method does not take that into account. For example: Bobby said boo

Comment: Referring to the question it only returns `false` if there are more than two `o` after `b` like `boooo`, and not more than two `o` in the whole string or it will never accept the example string of the question `Bob is boo` .

Comment: Thinking about it, I must admit that the question might be quite ambiguous in this matter. Referring to the question strictly, I still think the method should check for more `o`-s in the whole *String*, but if I were wrong, your answer would be correct :).

Answer (score 0):

You could have used regular expression, I consider it much more readable

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String word) {
    return word.toLowerCase().matches(".*?boo[^o]*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String word)
{
    word = word.toLowerCase() + " ";
    if(word.contains("boo") && word.length() > 3){
        if (word.charAt(word.indexOf("boo")+3) == 'o'){
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }else if(word.contains("boo")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I made a few small changes to your code and It appears to work now.
I made it check at the index of "boo" + 3 which would be whatever is following "boo". More than 2 o's results in false, just "boo" results in true.

Comment: Again, as commented on @chsdk's answer, you are not checking whether the *String* contains or not more than two `o` apart from the word *Boo*. Your function would return `true` with a String such as *Bobby said boo*, while it should return `false` (number of `o` exceeds 2).

Comment: Well if that is what is wanted , it is not ever clear in the question.

Comment: I might have precipitated in the assumption that it was looking for what I mentioned above. It will be better to wait for an update to clarify the objectives of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp as @camabeh has suggested. What is "readable" may depend on your current skill set, I remember I found regexps *very efficient* and *very unreadable* earlier.

An easier solution can be splitting your input into words, and simply check the words in a loop:

```
public static boolean ghostHunters(String sentence) {
    if (sentence == null)
        return false;
    }
    String[] words=sentence.toLowercase().split(" "); // split on word boundaries
    for (String word:words) {
        if (word.equals("boo")) {
            return true; 
        }  
    }
    // no match
    return false;
}
```

This ensures that "Bob has boobs" will return false, but "Bob says boo" is true, and "Bob missed and said booo" is false. (You might wish to tune the split to also split on tabs, new lines, etc. if you need to accept real-life sentences.)

I suggest to phrase your program so that it reveals your intention. This example above clearly reveals that we're splitting the sentence to words, and we compare then the words.

Your original example reveals a lot of internal string manipulation, therefore hard to understand. I would say it is too low level.

The regexp example from @camabeh is pretty neat, and serves you well once you're fluent with regexps. That is a (likely) too high level solution for a beginner's level CS problem.